# Read Data from IEC104 Protocol by PHP & Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I want to write the PHP and javascript code to read data from IEC 60-870-5-104, I know the protocol details, but I don't know how to write the required code, and you instructions would really make it easier.
It is for educational purpose, so the speed is not an issue, I just want to do it in PHP with/without javascript. Anyone out there who has an opinion, please share it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It would require a lot (half a year) of work to implement a useful subset of iec 104. It would be more efficient to use already existing implementation like https://www.openmuc.org/iec-60870-5-104/ and bridge it to PHP using something like http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/.

Or at least you can use existing implementation to guide you.